# How to make Celery worker consume single task and exit

Tags: python, kubernetes, celery, keda

How do I make the `celery -A app worker` command to consume only a single task and then exit.

I want to run celery workers as a kubernetes Job that finishes after handling a single task.

I'm using KEDA for autoscaling workers according to queue messages.
I want to run celery workers as jobs for long running tasks, as suggested in the documentation:
[KEDA long running execution](https://keda.sh/docs/1.5/concepts/scaling-deployments/#long-running-executions)

Comment: If all you need is to execute a single task, then I see no point of running Celery worker. Simply have a script in your container that just calls the same function that would otherwise be called by Celery...

Comment: I want to reuse celery infrastracture. Without it I'll need to implement producer consumer logic. Celery just makes it easier and gives alot of benefits. Also because I already use celery for small tasks with autoscaling deployments, I want the task calls to be consistent across the code.

Comment: I did not say you do not use celery infrastructure, just that you do not need Celery worker.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really anything specific for this. You would have to hack in your own driver program, probably via a custom concurrency module. Are you trying to use Keda ScaledJobs or something? You would just use a ScaledObject instead.

Comment: You need to go with the other approach listed there, ScaledObjects+Deployments+long-ass terminationGracePeriodSeconds. One of mine is 12 hours long :) It works fine, just as it says you'll see pods in Terminating for a while sometimes. Just make sure you tune your scale down cooldown time too so it doesn't happen too aggressively.

Comment: Also make sure you have have ACKS_LATE, a low prefetch multiplier, and use the `http` mode in Keda for RabbitMQ if that's your broker (not the `amqp` mode).

Comment: Feel free to ping me in #keda on Slack if you want more help, if the above isn't enough to make it clear, I revamped a lot of Keda specifically for Celery use cases and use a ton of it myself (hundreds of scalers).

Comment: I'm using RabbitMQ. Out of curiosity, why use `http`?

Comment: The `amqp` poller mode doesn't see messages sitting in unack'd and so will be over-aggressive in scaling down. `http` does see those, so combined with ACKS_LATE and you've got a more stable data source.